# init.d service working directory in OpenWrt

Tags: openwrt, sysvinit

Got an issue. I've written a simple C program that invokes certain shell script in randomized intervals - before it has been run as a cron task, but since there were many clients and each one run exactly at the same time, we needed to distribute load to avoid peaks. The script itself is placed in the /root directory and when it was executed by cron all the files it was working on were written in the same directory - /root/. When I switched to init.d service it started to write those files in the top dir - / .

The function I invoke the script looks like this:

```
 void execute_script(const char* url) {
    char command[MAX_URL_LENGTH + 15];
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "/root/updater.sh \"%s\"", url);
    system(command);
}
```

And the init.d script:

```
#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common
 
START=80
USE_PROCD=1

start_service() {
        procd_open_instance
        procd_set_param command /usr/bin/rndupd http://URL
        procd_set_param respawn
        procd_close_instance
}
```

How can I make this thing to operate in /root/ directory?

Comment: With `cd /root` near the beginning of your script.